# permanently block a mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I would like to know if it is possible to block the possibility of changing the root password on a mariadb. I have to distribute software with a mariadb database, and I don't want users to be able to access the database in any way (only through the application), so it must not be possible to change the root password. Is it possible? Thank you

Comment: Probably no. If they know the password they can change the password. Don't give out `root` or users with [excessive privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html).

Comment: If you distribute the software, you can't prevent them from doing anything they want. They have admin privileges on their own servers I assume, therefore they can always restart MariaDB with the `skip-grant-tables` option.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to lock mariadb down. All you would have to do is stop the mariadb service, restart it using `--skip-grant-tables` option and you can reset the root password.

Furthermore, users may have legitimate reasons accessing the database (backup, migration, password rotation, changing password after a breach), so locking them out is not a great idea. However, if they tamper with the database, all responsibility should rest with them.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB does not provide a way to deny a user access to their own password.

To prevent passwords from being changed, the `mysql/global_priv` (since 10.4.1, for older versions `mysql/user`) file in your data directory should be set to read-only.
This also means that no new users can be created.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create user foo@localhost;
ERROR 1036 (HY000): Table 'global_priv' is read only
```